# Customizing filters layout from joomla.searchtools.default for list view of custom component

Tags: jquery, joomla-4.x, filter

In Joomla 4, there is the layout `joomla.searchtools.default` for the filters in a list view that you can see everywhere in the BackEnd.

In a list view of my custom component (FrontEnd), I managed to apply the layout *joomla.searchtools.default* for the filters. All is working fine.

Now I want to customize the layout. To avoid touching core files, I made a copy of the templates in the layout (`joomla.searchtools.default`) to my custom component. All is working fine.

Specifically, I want to get rid of the "filter options" button (which hides and shows the filters), but keep the useful "clear" button. This way, users will always see the filters.

There is a template called `bar.php` where you can see the following code:

```
<div class="filter-search-actions btn-group">
    <?php if ($filterButton) : ?>
        <button type="button" class="filter-search-actions__button btn btn-primary js-stools-btn-filter">
            <?php echo Text::_('JFILTER_OPTIONS'); ?>
            <span class="icon-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" class="filter-search-actions__button btn btn-primary js-stools-btn-clear">
        <?php echo Text::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR'); ?>
    </button>
</div>
```

In the code snippet, you can see two buttons: `JFILTER_OPTIONS` and `JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR`

There is other template called `filters.php` that really displays the filters:

```
<?php if ($filters) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($filters as $fieldName => $field) : ?>
        <?php if ($fieldName !== 'filter_search') : ?>
            <?php $dataShowOn = ''; ?>
            <?php if ($field->showon) : ?>
                <?php $wa->useScript('showon'); ?>
                <?php $dataShowOn = " data-showon='" . json_encode(FormHelper::parseShowOnConditions($field->showon, $field->formControl, $field->group)) . "'"; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="js-stools-field-filter"<?php echo $dataShowOn; ?>>
                <span class="visually-hidden"><?php echo $field->label; ?></span>
                <?php echo $field->input; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How could I get rid of the `JFILTER_OPTIONS` button (without losing the visibility of the filters) and maintain the functionality of the `JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR` button?

All is related with the  `js-stools-container-filters` class in the divs' containers, I suppose, but I can't find more information.

Code snippet in the `default_filter.php` template (the "main" template):

```
// Load search tools
HTMLHelper::_('searchtools.form', $data['options']['formSelector'], $data['options']);
?>
<div class="js-stools" role="search">
    <?php if ($data['options']['showSelector']) : ?>
    <div class="js-stools-container-selector">
        <?php echo $this->sublayout('selector', $data); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="js-stools-container-bar">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <?php echo $this->sublayout('bar', $data); ?>
            <?php echo $this->sublayout('list', $data); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Filters div -->
    <div class="js-stools-container-filters clearfix<?php echo $filtersActiveClass; ?>">
        <?php if ($data['options']['filterButton']) : ?>
        <?php echo $this->sublayout('filters', $data); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if ($data['options']['showNoResults']) : ?>
    <?php echo $this->sublayout('noitems', $data); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ...just a small note about one of the snippets: Assuming `$filters` is either an empty or non-empty array, there is no benefit in wrapping a `foreach()` block in an `if()` block.  If the array is empty, then the `foreach()` will simply not iterate. If it is not empty, it will iterate. Removing the `if()` block will allow the `foreach()` block to move left 1 tab and reduce the need for humans to horizontally scroll to read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it (get rid of `JFILTER_OPTIONS` button, maintaining `JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR` button functionality) touching very little code:

At main filter template file (I named it `default_filter.php` in my component, it's the `default.php` in the layout `joomla.searchtools.default`) fixing the class `js-stools-container-filters-visible` in the filter's div:

```
<!-- Filters div -->
<div class="js-stools-container-filters clearfix js-stools-container-filters-visible">
```

In the `bar.php` sublayout, deleting the `JFILTER_OPTIONS` button, and leaving alone the `JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR` button:

```
<div class="filter-search-actions btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="filter-search-actions__button btn btn-primary js-stools-btn-clear">
        <?php echo Text::_('JSEARCH_FILTER_CLEAR'); ?>
    </button>
</div>
```

That's it !

Comment: Anyone knows if there are documentation available about "js-stools-container" and related classes ?